# Flutter: pass data to state

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm trying to pass data into a bloc which launches an API call, but I'm getting an error:

*"only static members can be accessed in initializers"*

Is this possible? Is my approach completely wrong?

I tried to switch the `postid` to static as well but unsure how I can actually access the `postid` in the state.

**Code:**

```
class ViewPost extends StatefulWidget {
   int postid; // sent from previous screen

}

ViewPost(
  {Key key,
  this.postid     
  })
  : super(key: key);
}
```

**State where I'd need to access the *postid*:**

```
@override
  _ViewPostState createState() => _ViewPostState();
}

class _ViewPostState extends State<ViewPost> {


final int postid; // somehow I'd need to access postid here

  final PostBlog _PostBloc =
  PostBloc(httpClient: http.Client(), postid: postid);
}



  _ViewBlogState() { 
_postBloc.dispatch(Fetch());
}
```

**Build:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.name),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: true,

    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () onPressed: ()  => Navigator.pop(context, true),

    ),
  ),

  body: new RefreshIndicator(
    child: BlocProviderTree(
        blocProviders: [
          PostProvider<PostBloc>(bloc: _postBloc)

        ],
        child: BlocBuilder(
          bloc: _postBloc,
          builder: (BuildContext context, PostState state) {
          ....

  }
```

Comment: remove `final int postid;` in the State class and use `widget.postid`. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went different route and got it working. Used the:

```
_postBloc.dispatch(Fetch(postid: postid));
```

to send it to event.

Then simply declared it in the event itself and after that it's accessible in the event.postid while making the api call.